# PL/SQL convert VARCHAR2 to row

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
  v_letter_c0 VARCHAR2(500) := 'c0';
  v_new_letter;
BEGIN

FOR my_number IN 1..70
   LOOP
FOR i IN (Select * From test_table)
   LOOP

    IF(my_number<=9) THEN
          v_new_letter := v_letter_c0 || my_number;

             UPDATE test_table y
             SET y.v_new_letter = replace(i.v_new_letter, ' ', '')
             WHERE y.v_new_letter = i.v_new_letter;

          END IF;

 END LOOP;
END LOOP;

END;
```

How can I convert TEXT in v_new_letter. Because I want to y.v_new_letter be for read.

Sorry I don't how say more correctly. 
But I want to say, how to do UPDATE will work?

Comment: Please try to better describe what you need to do. Some sample data and desired result ( as formatted text) with an expanation of the needed result would be useful. Here you find  something on [ask] and how to build a [mcve] that can be useful to improve your question

Answer (score 0):

It is very unclear from your description what you are attempting to achieve but you appear to be trying to replace spaces in `v_new_letter`.

You do not need the cursor and all the loops but can do it in a single SQL statement:

```
UPDATE test_table
SET    v_new_letter = replace( v_new_letter, ' ', '');
```

You appear to be trying to do something to match the strings `c01` through `c09` - but this is not used in your query. Maybe something like this:

```
UPDATE test_table
SET    v_new_letter = replace( v_new_letter, ' ', '')
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( v_new_letter, '^c0[1-9]$' );
```

Or for `c01` to `c70`:

```
UPDATE test_table
SET    v_new_letter = replace( v_new_letter, ' ', '')
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( v_new_letter, '^c(0[1-9]|[1-6]\d|70)$' );
```

However, if the `WHERE` clause matches then it will never have any spaces to replace so it is unclear what you want to achieve.

**Update**:

Based on your comment, you want to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE
  sql VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  FOR my_number IN 1..70 LOOP
    sql := 'UPDATE test_table'
           || ' SET c' || TO_CHAR( i, 'FM00' )
           || ' = replace( c' || TO_CHAR( i, 'FM00' ) || ', '' '' )';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: An error such, at me in the table there are columns which are called c01, c02 and etc. There is a cursor which is called "I." and after the dot go the column c01, c02, etc. But the problem is that after "I." I don't know how to insert c01, c02, etc so that they would be readable